# Contiki ng: how to lower power consumption?

Tags: c, embedded, iot, contiki, contiki-ng

Im currently developing a low power IoT node based on Contiki-ng running on a TI CC1350 launchpad board. My problem is that my power consumption is always >6mA.

Compiling and running the `energest` example I can see the MCU radio is always listening, no matter if I compile with `MAKE_MAC = MAKE_MAC_NULLMAC` and `MAKE_NET = MAKE_NET_NULLNET`. Running
`MAKE_MAC = MAKE_MAC_TSCH` or `MAKE_MAC = MAKE_MAC_CSMA` increases consumption by around 2mA as the CPU is always active, but the radio is never duty cycled.

Is there a way of reducing current consumption for Contiki-ng on this platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Contiki-NG, you have two options:

1. Use CSMA or NullMAC and turn off the radio from the application code with `NETSTACK_RADIO.off()`.
2. Use TSCH and make sure the schedule has some idle slots. The radio is going to turn off automatically once the node has joined a TSCH network.

If you the latter, still see big consumption, and you're sure about your code, submit an issue to the Contiki-NG git - there can be an energy consumption bug in the OS specific to the CC1350 board.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way of measuring "real world current with TSCH without joining a network? Currently I only have access to one board and would like to measure current without a full network. Also, could you clarify what you mean with making sure the schedule has some idle slots?

Comment: You are already apparently measuring current without joining a network. Its with radio always on. To reduce the current consumption, you need to join a network. A node can create its own network - set it in the TSCH coordinator role for that to happen.